What type of device is this on TP5000 Application Exapmle?
Data Sheet (Chinese)
Question 1
Component N1 looks similar to a mosfet but doesn't look like other ones that I have seen for N-Channel. What is this component supposed to be? This example is for LFP cell, so i assume this component leave CS hanging until the gate is activate which will conduct CS to ground and shutoff the TP5000.

Question 2
Am interpreting the functions of CS correctly?

CS=VIN --> sets operation mode to 4.2v charge max (lithium ion cells)
CS=NC --> floating sets charge max v to 3.6 v (LFP cell)
CS=GND --> grounding CS shuts off the charge IC so that the cell stop charging



CS stands for "current sense" which is used for monitoring output current draw. There's typically an internal shunt resistance that can help measure current draw. If the chip senses too much current draw, it'll likely shutdown the output voltage. The N-channel MOSFET likely acts a current mirror for the current sensing pin.

@Colin thanks. Your comment seems to differ from the data sheet though. It seems like it is the voltage control pin? I think TP4056 has a similar function. Could you explain what you mean by "current mirror"? THanks!
